# django - how to modify bcrypt or how to see its version?

Tags: django, bcrypt

I am building a website for a game server and they use bcrypt, so I do, but their hashes start with `$2a$12$` which I know that isn't secure, and my hashes start with `bcrypt_sha256$` if using bcrypt with sha256 or `bcrypt$` if using only bcrypt. How can I modify bcrypt to start with $2a$12? Also, how can I see the version to check if we have the same version.

Comment: This is documented: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/passwords/ Just be very careful when tampering with security features, Django is very secure and you could accidentally make it weaker.

Comment: @petr it doesnt tell me how to modify bcrypt settings, for example change prefix

Comment: It does: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.hashers I'm not saying it's a good idea to do so, but if that's what you need...